# Is it possible to dynamically specify the class name in styles?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I need to pass class name from script to style

```
<script
    lang="ts"
    setup
>
    const className = ref('some-class')
</script>

<style
    lang="sass"
    module
>
    .#{v-bind(className)}--dynamic
        pointer-events: none
</style>
```

In this case I get an error:
**Error: expected selector.
.v-bind(className)--dynamic ━ error in interpolated output**

**UPD: To clarify, I use this component in various others and I need the class to be with a prefix that I pass from the parent component**

Comment: `v-bind()` in CSS can't be used inside SCSS interpolation, because they run at different times, SCSS interpolation being the first (`sass` is a preprocessor). `sass` runs at compile time while `v-bind()` runs at runtime. In other words, `v-bind(className)` doesn't make any sense to `sass` and it is only replaced with the value of `className` in a later component lifecycle stage, long after `sass` has finished compiling the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

@Ilya Degtyarenko
You can specify your classes in the styles and use it like this:

```
<template>
  <div :class="[someClass]">
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const a = 10
  const someClass = a === 10 ? "success" : "error"
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.success {
}
.error {
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, the `v-bind` in style creates a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) that can be updated in style attribute of the element and used as value in the CSS rule :

```html
<p  style="--469af010-theme_color:red;">hello</p>
```

and

```css
p {
    color: var(--469af010-theme_color);
}
```

and it's not possible to use CSS var as class name.